# Formula for extracting bounding points from a given set of points

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, surfaces

I have a set of geographic locations, i.e. points defined by latitude and longitude. Given this set of points, I need to select only those of them that belong to the surface bounds.

The simplest algorithm that came to my mind is the following: If there is no other point to the left, right, top or down of the given point, then the given point belongs to the bound.

However this will not work for some particular cases.

Is there any formula for extracting bounding points from a given set of points?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a complex problem, even for planar case. You may look at Wiki articles on [extreme points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) and [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28convex_hull%29) to form the intuition for this problem.